# How to skip the styles to specific parent element using CSS3

Tags: css

I have the HTML page structure in the following way, But i want to apply the styles only to the specific page.

Here, how do i skip the styles for "signup-step2"

```
<signup-step2 class="ion-page show-page" style="z-index: 100;">
  <ion-header></ion-header>
  <ion-content class="signup-page content content-md" padding="" style="">
  </ion-content>
</signup-step2>
```

I try to apply using **:not**, but not working.

```
ion-content{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  :not(signup-step2) ion-content:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;     
      background: url('../assets/img/content-bg.png') 44% 100%;     
      opacity: .2;
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you can walk UP the flow in CSS. You'll need to apply `ion-page` at ion-page's level

Comment: Can you show us more code, or an example of what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to your block when it is used for signup, and use this class as the `not()` selector. It makes the code easier to read and maintain.

```css
ion-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

signup-step2:not(.signup)>ion-content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('../assets/img/content-bg.png') 44% 100%;
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<signup-step2 class="ion-page show-page" style="z-index: 100;">
  <ion-header></ion-header>
  <ion-content class="signup-page content content-md" padding="" style="">
  </ion-content>
</signup-step2>
```